# Access denied from remote MySQL server

Tags: mysql, remote-access, trust

Trying to connect to hostB, I use the command below from hostA:

mysql --database=mydb --user=myuser --password=mypassword --host=hostB

As a response I get the message:
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'myuser'@'x.x.x.x (IP of hostA)' (using password: YES)

When manually changing the host field on mysql.user on hostB to be the IP of hostA and flush privileges, I can do the remote access.

Why does hostB identifies hostA by its IP address and not by FQDN? I can ping hostA from hostB by FQDN and do reverse lookup.

I’ve set that kind of remote access many times, and never had any problem with this.

Comment: The changes to my.cnf are about disk size. Nothing related. And it is the same configuration I use for other hosts. Nothing special.

Regarding the article, the nslookup is working and the server is started without any flags, just "service mysqld start"

Comment: so both your forward and revers lookup is working?? hmmm...not sure what the issues is then...